# PhP Html Inside String Causing Error

Tags: php, escaping

PHP Parese Error unexpected &gt and array variable not being printed

### PHP

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
            $obj = $_POST['myData'];
            $debug_export = var_export($obj, true);
            for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($obj); $row++) {

             //echo $obj[$row]['place'].$obj[$row]['Distance'];
                $strRow = "<tr><td> <a href=\"#\" class=\"SResult\" onClick=\"initializePopBefore(this);return false;\">$obj[$row]['place']</a><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"Lat$row\" value=\"$obj[$row]['Lat']\"/><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"Lng$row\" value=\"$obj[$row]['Lng']\"/></td><td>$obj[$row]['Distance']</td></tr>";
              echo  $strRow;
         }
            $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") ;
            $txt = "John Doe\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $debug_export);
            fclose($myfile);
   }else{
           echo "File Working";
   }
?>
```

Failing to find what I am doing wrong stuck with this for few hours

Comment: someone edited your question and added the double quote. I performed a rollback. Please... people, do NOT fix code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have failed to find it just two days into php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I noticed that but the error persists

Comment: @Fred-ii- Notice Array To string Conversion and am using notepad++

Comment: `PHP Parese Error unexpected &gt` is that the real error with `&gt` or is it `PHP Parese Error unexpected >`? that is 2 different things/errors. Plus, I doubt what you posted is causing the error and may be something else. However, it could and may be in something in variables/queries you're not showing us. Edit: more answers below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is the value inside place variable BAKE 'N' COOLHelo

Comment: `$place` that's a variable. If you mean what's inside `$obj[$row]['place']` then that's an array. Try removing the quotes for it or escaping them `$obj[$row][\'place\']` . Again, you have more answers below, see if those work/help. You need to let them know if it worked or not. They don't know yet if it did or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Solved the problem dont know what caused problem but i changed the assigned $place=$obj[$row]['place'];
   $Lat =$obj[$row]['Lat'];
   $Lng =$obj[$row]['Lng'];
   $distance=$obj[$row]['Distance']; and after that used these variables inside the anwer suggested by Victory and it worked but before taking out array out of it Even victorys answer dint work after this yes it worked

Comment: Glad to hear it, cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanx alot for your effort trying to use php for last two days in an application its like jumping into ocean praying you learn swimming before you drown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be much easier to read and maintain if you use a PHP `HEREDOC` which uses the syntax like so:

```
$strRow = <<<AROW
<tr>
   <td>
     <a href="#" class="SResult" onClick="initializePopBefore(this);return false;">
       $obj[$row]['place']
     </a>
     <input type="hidden" id="Lat$row" value="$obj[$row]['Lat']"/>
     <input type="hidden" id="Lng$row" value="$obj[$row]['Lng']"/>
   </td>
   <td>$obj[$row]['Distance']</td>
</tr>
AROW;
```

[see the offical HEREDOC documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 1):

Never use escaping of html, but use single quotes for your strings:

```
$strRow = '<tr><td><a href="#" class="SResult" onClick="initializePopBefore(this);return false;">' . $obj[$row]['place'] . '</a><input type="hidden" id="Lat$row" value="' . $obj[$row]['Lat'] . '"/><input type="hidden" id="Lng$row" value="' . $obj[$row]['Lng'] . '"/></td><td>' . $obj[$row]['Distance'] . '</td></tr>';
```

Secondly, use php vars outside the quotes!